# MediaPlayer isn't working

Tags: java, javafx, mp3

How do I use MediaPlayer to play m4a files? 
This is my code:

```
public void audioPlayerButtons(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       String bip = "Songs/01 Clarity.m4a";
       Media hit = new Media(bip);
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);

       if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {
           mediaPlayer.play();

       } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == pausebtn) {
           mediaPlayer.pause();

       } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == forwardbtn) {
           mediaPlayer.stop();

       } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == backwardbtn) {
           mediaPlayer.isAutoPlay();
       }
```

but it's throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
```

could you please help me understand why?

Basically, my aim is to make a mp3 player using mediaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs for the `Media` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-):

> The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. Only HTTP,
>   FILE, and JAR URLs are supported. If the provided URL is invalid then
>   an exception will be thrown.

The value you provided (`"Songs/01 Clarity.m4a"`) is certainly not a valid URI, as it has whitespace.

You need something like

```
String bip = getClass().getResource("Songs/01 Clarity.m4a").toExternalForm();
```

(which will try to find the song relative to the current class, and is useful if you intend to bundle the m4a files with your application), or

```
String bip = new File("Songs/01 Clarity.m4a").toURI().toString();
```

which will look for the file on the file system, relative to the working directory.

In either case, you will likely need to change the path to get it correct.